# Chakra UI type problem with useDisclosure

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I'm trying to use the alert dialog example from chakra ui docs, but I got some issues with typing:

```
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
    {...}
        <AlertDialog
                    motionPreset="slideInBottom"
                    leastDestructiveRef={cancelRef}
                    onClose={onClose}
                    isOpen={isOpen}
                    isCentered
        >
                <Button ref={cancelRef} onClick={onClose}>
                    Cancel
                </Button>
        </AlertDialog>
```

I got the following errors from the leastDestructiveRef and ref:

> Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type
> 'RefObject'.
>
> Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type
> 'LegacyRef | undefined'.

Comment: Could you share an executable of your code in `codesandbox`?

Comment: Try this: `const cancelRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);`.  If that doesn't resolve the issue then you are going to need to share more code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue with Chakra. As in Linda Paiste's answer, this fixed it for me:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
...
const cancelRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
```